# select values greater than the average

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, sum

I have two tables and i need to find the drivers who have delivered more than the average number of packages carried by all drivers and how much **more** than the average. The first table i'm showing is the Package table and the 2nd is the Truck table. I know i need to use a count but i cannot figure out how to combine that with the average

```
Truck_no
103 
105 
102 
108 
108 
108 
101 
109 
109 
100 
100 
100 


Truck_no Drivername
100 JONES
101 DAVIS
102 GOMEZ
103 THOMPSON
104 HERSHEY
105 FERRIS
106 SHAVER
107 LEE
108 TOPI
109 ACKERMAN
```

this is my Query so far

```
select drivername, count(package.truck_no) as PackageCount
from PACKAGE, truck
where truck.TRUCK_NO=PACKAGE.TRUCK_NO
group by drivername
```

and i get these results

```
Drivername      Packagecount
ACKERMAN    2
DAVIS           1
FERRIS          1
GOMEZ           1
JONES           3
THOMPSON    1
TOPI            3
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks a lot

Comment: MySQL does unexpected grouping when you use `sum` and `count` etc, so in this case I'd say you should run two queries, the first one will calculate the average, and the second (main) one will select `where Packagecount > {insert average}` - you could do that with a serverside language (PHP, ASP, etc)

Comment: Thanks. I thought about using a subqueries but I cant take the average of the truck_no

Comment: Can you post your inputs and expected output clearly...

Comment: I just need to find the average amount of packages the trucks have delivered (the occurrences are in the first table) and then specify which drivernames have delivered more than the average and by how much they have. i should get 3 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT drivername, packagecount
      FROM (   SELECT drivername, COUNT(1) AS packagecount
                 FROM truck
            LEFT JOIN package
                      ON truck.truck_no = package.truck_no
             GROUP BY 1) all_driver_counts
CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT AVG(n) AS avg_packagecount
              FROM (  SELECT truck_no, COUNT(1) AS n
                        FROM package
                    GROUP BY 1) truck_packages) the_average
     WHERE packagecount > avg_packagecount;
```

This produces:

```
+------------+--------------+
| drivername | packagecount |
+------------+--------------+
| ACKERMAN   |            2 |
| JONES      |            3 |
| TOPI       |            3 |
+------------+--------------+
```

Reading the above query bottom-up, we compute the average packages delivered per truck (`the_average`) and join that with each driver's counts (`all_driver_counts`), filtering only those rows WHERE a driver's count exceeds the average.

Analytic (SQL sliding window) functions might have made the above query easier, but, alas, MySQL does not support them.